# Get all users with one role or another using Eloquent

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to display a list of users with the role of 'admin' or 'webmaster'. I can get it to work when specifying only one role but when I try to get both by adding an orWhere clause it returns all of the users regardless of their role.

```
$admins = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'Admin');
})->paginate(25);
```

I've tried the following but it returns all of the users with every role.

```
$admins = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->where('name', 'Admin')
        ->orWhere('name', 'Webmaster');
})->paginate(25);
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how to accomplish this? For reference I have a users table, a roles table, and a role_user table that is a many-to-many from roles to users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$admins = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
    $q->whereIn('name', ['Admin', 'Webmaster'] );
})->paginate(25);
```

Comment: That's not querying the `roles` relation.

Comment: That gives me what I was looking for. Thank you for the help, I greatly appreciate it.